# Magento 2: Custom module to override the logo.phtml file of the custom theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, phtml, template-override, theme-overriding

Naming the custom module to override the logo.phtml file found at the path seen in the screenshot below a bit confusing to me as the module name is too long to decide on the naming. The vendor of the custom theme being used is Swissup.

I know the module name should begin with Swissup_(What comes here) with me not being able to figure out how to complete the module name after Swissup_. 
Any advice or help, please.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the logo.phtml file under your custom module by making preference for `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo` class.

Add di.xml file under `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` with below content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Html\Header\Logo"/>
</config>
```

After that, create `Logo.php` under `app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Rewrite/Html/Header` with below content.

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Html\Header;

class Logo extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo
{
    /**
     * Current template name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::html/header/logo.phtml';
}
```

Copy the `logo.phtml` file from your theme and placed under `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/html/header`.

Run the deployment commands and check your changes.

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: thanks for your time and the help. Could the module name be anything? Will it do if I name it as Swissup_Logo or Mycompanyname_Logo?

Comment: Yes, you can change the name of the module whatever you want. Also, please add all required files to create a module Registration.php and module.xml.

Comment: I am trying your solution now. In `type="Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Html\Header\Logo"` do I need to replace the Vendor with my company name and Module with module name?

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can replace it with your names. Please make sure you can change the names in the Logo.php file as well.

Comment: Followed all the instructions by you, but the logo part itself is now missing from the homepage. I wonder what must have gone wrong.

Comment: Have you copied logo.phtml in the given path?

Comment: Yes, I did. copied it to where you said I should.

Comment: Yes Sumit, I have done that as I am familiar with it. I already have two other custom modules in this project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107297/discussion-between-sumit-and-codeforgood).

Comment: Also, I replaced Veno_Module in this line `protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::html/header/logo.phtml';`

Answer (score 0):

You can manage via **after** plugin on `getTemplate()` .

**Create `di.xml` at `app/code/StackExchange/Theme/etc/frontend`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchange_Theme_Plugin_Magento_Theme_Block_Html_Header_Logo" sortOrder="10" type="StackExchange\Theme\Plugin\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then on  plugin class `StackExchange\Theme\Plugin\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo.php` and

from `afterGetTemplate()` changes template from here.

```
<?php  declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchange\Theme\Plugin\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header;

class Logo
{

    public function afterGetTemplate(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        return 'StackExchange_Theme::html/header/logo.phtml';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help.I presume I must replace app/code/StackExchange/Theme/etc/frontend with app/code/MyCompanyName/Swissup/etc/frontend. Is this correct?

Comment: yes.. `app/code/StackExchange/Theme/etc/frontend`